# How do I prevent the top and left portions of a modal dialog from being inaccessible when I shrink the size far enough to overflow

Tags: html, css, typescript

I'm having some issues with part of a fixed size modal dialog getting cut off and being inaccessible when I shrink the window far enough to cause an overflow.  Specifically, if I make the window really narrow horizontally part of the left will be cut off and inaccessible.  If I make it really short vertically, part of the top will be cut off and not accessible either when scrolling.

I'm going to include a fiddle at the bottom with a simple example showing it.  Basically, I have a modal service that declares its' own html and css like in the fiddle and has the ".modal-" prefixes.  It has a fixed size that takes up the full screen and it has a body div inside that is meant to wrap the dialog passed in from elsewhere that can be basically anything and any size (typically fixed though such as in the example, but varying sizes since it makes use of several different dialogs).  What is passed in is represented by the ".dialog-container" class.  Does anyone know of a way to overcome these issues without breaking the functionality I have nor assuming a set size for the dialog passed in?  I've been stuck for a bit.  The fiddle is here and I guess I'm required to include code too so it'll be below as well:  https://jsfiddle.net/zrb42vex/

```
<div class="modal">
<div class="modal-body">
    <div class="dialog-container">
      Top
    </div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="modal-background"></div>

        .modal {
      position: fixed;
      top: 0;
      right: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      left: 0;
      z-index: 1000;
      overflow: auto;
    }
    
    .modal-body {
        position: absolute;
        height: fit-content;
        width: fit-content;
        background: #fff;
        border-radius: 5px;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    }
    
    .modal-background {
      position: fixed;
      top: 0;
      right: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      left: 0;

      background-color: #000;
      opacity: 0.75;
    
      z-index: 900;
    }
    
    .dialog-container {
        height: 500px;
        width: 600px;
        padding: 20px;
    }
```

Snippet:

```css
.modal {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1000;
  overflow: auto;
}

.modal-body {
  position: absolute;
  height: fit-content;
  width: fit-content;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.modal-background {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #000;
  opacity: 0.75;
  z-index: 900;
}

.dialog-container {
  height: 500px;
  width: 600px;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="modal">
  <div class="modal-body">
    <div class="dialog-container">
      Top
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="modal-background"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Feels like what you describe is flex.  Here I put some borders on and a pink background just to illustrate with some content I added where it "lived".
I could enhance the content by making part of it flex which I did some to the contents.

EDIT: Updated to set a fixed size on `.dialog-container`

```css
.modal {
  position: fixed;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1000;
  overflow: auto;
  border: solid 1px red;
}

.modal-body {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: solid 2px lime;
}

.modal-background {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #ffdddd;
  opacity: 0.75;
  z-index: 900;
}

.dialog-container {
  width: 300px;
  height: 250px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  /* stack them */
  align-items: center;
  padding: 20px;
  border: solid 3px blue;
}

.home-run {
  justify-self: flex-start;
  width: 15rem;
  height: 4rem;
  border: 1px solid #ddffdd;
  background-color: #ddddff;
  /* align the text in the middle of the div */
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="modal">
  <div class="modal-body">
    <div class="dialog-container">
      Top of the morning to you I have more fun stuff like this span: <span>I am a span</span>
      <div class="home-run">I am a div so I do a div</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="modal-background"></div>
```

Comment: I don't really see any way to make this work with what I'm trying to do.  I have some fairly complex layouts that are in some of those dialogs and they have a requirement of needing to support a set constant height/width in the main dialog container.  Any suggestion as to how to have it work with those requirements in mind?

Comment: @RBrown - just set the size on the container if that is a strict requirement but feels "odd" given the large content you noted.  Let me update for that...

Comment: Updated, so as you now see the "fixed size" requirement and "smaller window" requirement conflict the way you have it - so likely you will have to sett your container window to scroll around which feels "messy" - I would suggest moving to a "responsive" layout OR you just force people to have big windows.